# Following REST routes based on conditions

Tags: php, rest, routes

Context: I'm developing a turn-based game that requires client-server communication. The client uses RESTful requests via HTTPS and the server uses JSON responses. I'm not using REST because I need to expose the API, but because the REST paradigm was comfortable to get the client/server interaction sorted out. The server is to be written in PHP.

To help me out with routing the REST requests I've been searching for a useful routing library. There are a staggering amount of them available, but I have difficulties finding one that fits my specific needs. My problem is this: a player should only be allowed to follow certain routes if certain conditions are met. Obviously I can check if the conditions are met in the method that is called after a route match, but this seems an error-prone approach because conditions are the same for many routes. It would be much simpler to first do a partial match, then decide some conditions must be met to follow more specific routes under the partial match.

To illustrate, there are 4 levels of 'authentication' in the game:

1. Not authenticated
2. Authenticated as {id} (we know which player it is)
3. Authenticated as {id} and participant in session {sesid}
4. Authenticated as {id}, participant in session {sesid}, AND it's the player's turn

Assume for now that authentication happens in the background. Routes you can follow on each level, progressively:

LEVEL 1:

- POST \Players- sign up

LEVEL 2:

- PUT \Players\{id} - change profile
- GET \Players\{id}\Sessions - get list of sessions
- POST \Players\{id}\Sessions - create session
- POST\Players\{id}\Inventory - buy items
- PUT \Players\{id}\Invites\{sesid} - join invitation for session
- DELETE \Players\{id}\Invites\{sesid} - decline invitation for session

LEVEL 3:

- GET \Players\{id}\Sessions\{sesid} - get session state
- DELETE \Players{id}\Sessions\{sesid} - cancel session

LEVEL 4:

- PUT \Players\{id}\Sessions\{sesid}\... - set several session state parameters

So I wish to be check a few parameters up front before matching the next set of routes. I've spent quite some Google and Packagist time finding a suitable routing package (I've looked at the docs for Klein, Zend, PHP-Router, Fat_free, Slim, TORO, Aura, FlightPHP, Phalcon, FuelPHP to name but a few) but almost all libraries require that you define routes up front and find a single match in one go - sometimes allowing you to set an order, and sometimes going from most specific to least specific, but mostly executing only one route.

I would be somewhat helped if I could do a partial route match in a defined order - for example, any route starting with players\{id} first checks authentication, exits when it's not there, whilst continuing to check the next pattern in defined order if authentication is OK.

Any routing library that would allow me to match and execute a route on the spot would also help - provided that it can do partial matches so that I can pick up parameters I require to check the authentication level requirements (id, sesid). Obviously, to keep things slim I'd prefer a library that is not part of a larger framework.

From the documentation pages I've read at Packagist, I have difficulties finding out if you can partially match routes in certain libraries - match parameters, yes, but routes? - and sometimes it's unclear if the first match found is the only match. Any pointers?

Or am I missing a more straightforward solution here?

Comment: The best option is to just write it yourself or to find a framework that come close to your needs, and alter it.

Comment: I agree somewhat with the sentiment, but I'm fairly new to PHP - this is why I hope to solve it with a library (I'm going to be using several - PHP is such a time winner with those vast libraries of packages), as opposed to writing my own; let alone delving into the code base of other developers. I'm not entirely comfortable yet with string routines that filter out parts of the URI, match patterns as values, do some validation of the result and then pass them off as parameters to a method.

Comment: I know for sure with Slim you can use RegEx to match URLs, so while it's not ideal and might end up looking a bit ugly, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks, but according to the documentation Slim only acts on the first match. I'd first need to check a partial match to verify an authentication level, and then continue with more specific matches, in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start with, [Klein](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) will let you execute more than one route for the same callback, like this:

```
// This route matches everything
$klein->respond('*', function ($request, $response, $service) { myAuthFunction($request); });
//other routes
// This route matches only a specific path
$klein->respond('GET', '/Players/[i:id]/Sessions', function ($request, $response, $service) { echo "This is the Sessions page for User ID $request->id"; })
```

Check out the section on [routing](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php#routing), and scroll to the paragraph that starts with "Note."  If I remember correctly, the routes are executed in the order they are declared, so you catch all route you use for checking credentials would need to be first, before the more specific ones.

In your auth function, you need to throw an exception, in order to prevent the later route from being run, and then catch it.  [This link](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php/wiki/Handling-404's) shows how to catch throw HTTP errors.  To throw one, simply call `$router->abort(404)` inside your callback.  You have to send $router (your Klein instance ) using use, so your callback would actually be:

```
$klein->respond('*', function ($request, $response, $service) use ($klein) { myAuthFunction($request); });
```

There's also a routing [namespace](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php#route-namespaces) system, which I looked at, but haven't used myself, but might be helpful for what you're trying to do.

Lastly, what I ended up doing, was grouping my actions into Controllers, and doing a permission check in the constructor for the controller.  I don't want to waste a lot of time explaining how to set that up if you don't think it's going to be relevant for you, but I can provide more details upon request.

A final note, the docs say to install Klein like this:

```
php composer.phar require klein/klein v2.0.x
```

But I've found that the dev-master code works better, so I would recommend doing this:

```
php composer.phar require klein/klein dev-master
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks! Looks like I overlooked the note when I skimmed the Klein documentation. Your example helps greatly. Regarding the controller, I've considered that, but found it cumbersome to group actions into controllers by permissions. I'll go try Klein now. :)

Comment: I've really enjoyed my experience with Klein.  The code is well-written, and the API both simple and powerful.  It does a good job of doing what it needs to do without telling you what to do.  Hope it works as well for your needs.  If you run into any issues, the developer is pretty good about answering Issues on the GitHub repo.  I also try to keep an eye out for Klein-related questions on SO and on GitHub.  And lastly, don't be afraid to dive into the code.  It's a small, well-written project, and I've learned a fair bit from doing the same.  Enjoy!

Comment: Will do, sounds like a keeper. Thanks for your suggestions, much appreciated.